# How to put timestamp on bluemix iot payload of connected device

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot, node-red

How do i put timestamp on the msg payload from each streaming devices.
and also those timestamp should be from device timezone.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function node to obtain a timestamp and add that to the msg.payload data. Here is how I produced a timestamp in a function node:

```
var tstamp=(new Date).toISOString().replace(/t/gi,' ').trim();
```

To add a timestamp depending on the device timezone you would need to know where the device is located. This might be even more complex if the device is mobile.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Actually i publish timezone information from device as well "Asia/Bangkok" something like this but i don't how to handle it with server timezone